# AJAX not getting parsed value from controller

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, model-view-controller

I've been working for all day on my website. Now I encountered a problem. I watched many YouTube videos and searched all over the internet to get it to work, but somehow it won't.

I'm trying to load data from through an ajax function which is linked to the controller in my Laravel application. However, if I respond with the data and console.log this, nothing will show.

If I go directly to the link, it shows this.

```
[{"id":54,"username":"test1","flights":"test1","hours":5,"planes":"test2","age":"24"}]
```

This is what my controller function looks like:

```
 public function showInTable()
{
   $values= flights::all()->where('username', Auth::user()->username);
   return response($values);
}
```

This is what my jQuery looks like:

```
function getTableInfo()
{
    $.get("flight/showInTable", function(data){
        console.log(data);
    })
};
```

The console.log doesn't do anything. I hope someone will be able to help me with this.

Comment: Just try with `echo $values` instead of return the values as a response if not working than try `return response()->json($values)`. But I guess the json returning wont effect anything but still try that

Comment: @AnikethSaha If I do that and I look at my console, it still returns nothing. It's just empty. https://gyazo.com/6a7297f05feb695378416405956d4761

Comment: Switch to the network tab of your console and verify that a request to `flight/showInTable` is being made: if it is, use the `response` tab on the request to check the return value.

Comment: @sam thanks! I found the answer! I made a little mistake in my routes.